# Loading images from a folder using angular

Tags: angular

I am a newbie to angular and I am developing a web app where I am supposed to display a carousel. I have the images that should be displayed in a folder under assets. (assets/frames) I want to load this images to an array so that I can display them in the carousel. Any way of doing this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const imageUrls = ['assets/frames/1.jpg', 'assets/frames/2.jpg', 'assets/frames/3.jpg']`?

Comment: @JBNizet Here I can't hard code the image urls because whenever the app is run, a different number of images will be generated and I need to display all of them in the carousel. I guess it has to go with *ngFor

Comment: You need some kind of web service that will return the list of images in the assets folder